# Проблема с "подкапотными" процессами SimpleCursorAdapter-а

Tags: java, android, база-данных, cursoradaper

Обобщенно.
В фрагменте есть ListView, к нему подключен кастомный адаптер extends SimpleCursorAdapter. Проблема заключается в неизвестном процессе происходящем "под капотом" адаптера, делающий работу интерфейса в определенной ситуации некорректной.

Суть.
При добавлении пользователем нового города, в БД сначала добавляется текст "Идет загрузка..." для заглушки, одновременно с этим происходит запрос данных с сервера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

... при получении которых заглушка меняется на эти данные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

... на данном этапе, все хорошо. Далее удаляю любой из пунктов и добавляю что-нибудь новое, и по неизвестной мне причине, теперь к заглушке "о загрузке" добавляются иконка и информация от предыдущего удаленного пункта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

...после получения погодных данных с сервера все норм:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код кастомного адаптера:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import ru.igorsharov.weatherapp.DataHandler.DataWeatherHandler;
import ru.igorsharov.weatherapp.R;


public class CustomSimpleAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private String[] from;

    public CustomSimpleAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
        this.from = from;
    }

    private String getCurrentColumn(Cursor cursor, String from) {
        return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(from));
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        final String[] mFrom = from;

        String cityName = getCurrentColumn(cursor, mFrom[0]);
        TextView tvCity = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCityName);
        setViewText(tvCity, cityName);


        String temperature = getCurrentColumn(cursor, mFrom[1]);
        if (temperature != null) {
            TextView tvTemperature = view.findViewById(R.id.tvTemperature);
            tvTemperature.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvTemperature.setTextColor(DataWeatherHandler.colorOfTemp(context, temperature));
            tvTemperature.setText(DataWeatherHandler.addDegree(temperature));
        }

        String idIconWeatherToday = getCurrentColumn(cursor, mFrom[2]);
        if (idIconWeatherToday != null) {
            ImageView imgView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            // достаем путь к ресурсу для иконки
            String iconStr = String.valueOf(DataWeatherHandler.getIconId(idIconWeatherToday));
            imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setViewImage(imgView, iconStr);
        }

    }
}
```

данную часть кода адаптера проверял логами, проблемы не нашел, где-то они кэшируются самим адаптером.

Comment: Покажите где и как вы берете `Cursor`, по науке надо брать его через `CursorLoader` - подозреваю, что у вас что-то не в порядке с ним

Comment: соглашусь с Barmaley скорее всего ошибка в логике использования Cursor

Comment: с помощью db.getReadableCursor()

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема в том, что взятие `Cursor`а должно происходить асинхронно, то есть вне UI треда. Как пишут об этом умные люди:

> Prior to Honeycomb, it was difficult to manage cursors, synchronize correctly with the UI thread, and ensure all queries occurred on a background thread. Android 3.0 introduced the Loader and LoaderManager classes to help simplify the process. Both classes are available for use in the Android Support Library, which supports all Android platforms back to Android 1.6.

Вам надо использовать `LoaderManager`, который берет на себя "подкапотную" работу с обновлением курсора.

Краткая [инструкция здесь](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html)

Comment: Переделал фрагмент на использование LoaderManager'а. Проблема сохранилась. Не знаю нужен ли код к данному комментарию.

Comment: У меня подозрение все-таки на работу адаптера, т.к. он рассчитывает на работу с 3-мя элементами в Item-е, а в базе видит только один и пустые заполняет откуда-то из своего кэша. Причем если не заменять инфо о загрузке, а так и оставить, то при перезагрузке приложения ненужная информация исчезает.

Comment: понимаю что можно уйти от ситуации и переделать логику ожидания, но уже принципиально интересно узнать в чем дело